# So, we have $ABCD$ a parallelogram, and three points $M$, $N$, $P$ on $AB$, $BC$ and $CD$ such that the center of the parallelogram ...

Tags: geometry

So, we have $ABCD$ a parallelogram, and three points $M$, $N$, $P$ on $AB$, $BC$ and $CD$ such that the center of the parallelogram is the center of gravity of $\Delta MNP$. Show that N is the midle of BC. I have literally no idea. Thanks!!

---

I will be short, sorry, my time is very limited. I have to show that
$\Delta CON\equiv\Delta BON$, which is very simple.

Comment: Can you do it when $ABCD$ is a rectangle?

Comment: Yeah, it s very easy like that!

Comment: Edit your question to show the proof for the case of rectangles and then think about how to apply the same argument to parallelograms.

Answer (score 1):

Extend $NT$ to $E\in MP$. Then $E$ halves $PM$, so $$d(E,AB) = {1\over 2}d(AB,CD)$$
and the sam is true for $T$ (since diagonals in parallelogram halves each other): $$d(T,AB) = {1\over 2}d(AB,CD)$$

So $ET||AB$ and thus $EM||AB$ so: $$d(N,AB) = {1\over 2}d(AB,CD)$$ and thus $N$ halves $BC$.